# .NET Core API Documentation

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to implement API documentation and make use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer` in my fresh .net core project. I've followed every step in this tutorial:

https://andrewlock.net/introduction-to-the-apiexplorer-in-asp-net-core/

yet im getting this exception:

```
    Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, out ConstructorInfo matchingConstructor, out Nullable<int>[] parameterMap)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelActivatorProvider.CreateActivator(CompiledPageActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DefaultPageModelFactoryProvider.CreateModelFactory(CompiledPageActionDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvokerProvider.CreateCacheEntry(ActionInvokerProviderContext context, FilterItem[] cachedFilters)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Internal.PageActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RouteAsync>b__0(HttpContext c)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It seems like the object reference in `DocumentationController` is never passed in. 
In ASP.Net you can just simply generate the help pages. Can anyone please explain me how to properly use the `ApiExplorer` or provide an alternative solution for creating Web API docs?

Comment: Hey there. It's going to be difficult to help with what you have provided thus far. Could you add the exception message and your code? I'm guessing it might be your controller class that is causing the problem. Do you have more than one constructor?

Comment: Try swagger. it is much easier to implement with much more features. You can test run the APIs and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided was created in 2017, prior to the release of .NET Core 2.0. There was a huge difference between 2.0 and its past releases. The documentation you have shown belongs has codes used on 1.x. I suggest you check out swagger. Here is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio) of how to set it up step by step. You basically mostly need to update your startup.cs file. The code in `Startup` will help generate a JSON file containing all info on your web API. The `UseSwaggerUI` function will then help you to generate a complete swagger UI. The UI comes complete with options do directly run and test the API including authentication.

Swagger is not specific to .NET and its json output is quite generic and popular. Microsoft and several others have started integrating tools to swagger's json file as well. This means as long as you have a swagger json setup for your API, you can also take advantage of these tools. For instance, you can generate the consuming code (coming up on December in version 2.2) or even generate the entire client-side on UWP. I am quite sure other popular technologies like react and angular would have auto-generation tools once you use swagger as well.

Comment: I had read about Swagger on the .NET core documentation. I was trying to find a solution integrated to the actual framework but looks like this is the best option s ofar. Anyway, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Integrated in what ways? the upcoming version 2.2 has additional features that integrate with swagger. With Microsoft working so much to integrate with and from swagger, I don't think they would be making a first party solution

Comment: have a look at this updated implementation using the new framework that released yesterday https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_vw3hcnSA1Y